# return single array from json by passing a value

Tags: php

I have a json that I need to filter a specific key and value from

the following json

```
{
"5": {
      "Owner": "94EAC",
      "Record":"0121ln"
},
"15": {
      "Owner": "009AC",
      "Record":"0120Pc"
},
"1": {
      "Owner": "00G11A",
      "Record":"000lPcn"
},
"199": {
      "Owner": "00G1y9",
      "Record":"01211cn"
},
"33": {
      "Owner": "001AC",
      "Record":"0121n"
}
```

}

I would like to be able to pass the first int and get back array for that number.
For example if I pass 15 I get

```
 {
      "Owner": "009AC",
      "Record":"0120Pc"
}
```

I tried foreach loop but cannot set specific value for the first int

```
If I assign $data = json
```

then $date[15] didn't work
$data->15 also didn't work

I did also use the json decode and was able to print an array but wasn't able to get a single value
Any help would be great, I did spend all day and still cannot get an answer.
Thank you

Comment: Did "didn't work" materialize as an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Using Array:
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
print_r( $arr['15']);

Using Object:
$obj = json_decode($json);
print_r( $obj['15']);
```

Reference: [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Thank you so much, I was missing the '' I was passing the number without the ''

Comment: Just remember if you are accessing a variable index, prefer to use square brackets. :)